# How can I determine what is printing on my console?

Tags: logs, console, syslog

[image]

how determine the owner of this output??  what is  flooding my console?

udev 
syslog
syslogng?

**edit to accepted answer:**

I'll accept answer but...

- I don't use init instead I use systemd.
- kernel logging level is set in sysctl.conf
- best way for this case was to compare entries in syslog with those from stdout and check label indeed it is from [kernel]

to hide kernel specyfic edit sysctl conf file and:

```
#
# Uncomment the following to stop low-level messages on console
# see also: 
#    http://superuser.com/questions/351387/how-to-stop-kernel-messages-from-flooding-my-console
#

kernel.printk = 3 4 1 3
```

Comment: I see no reason to downvote this Q. It shows own thinking.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is the kernel itself who is flooding your console.

You need to lower loglevel for consoles: `sudo dmesg -n 1`.

The system may have a setting for this (including bootloader one). Otherwise to make this permanent, you need to add this to your `/etc/rc.local`.

Note that this affects only postboot behavior of console, to shut off it from boot time, you need to set `loglevel=1` kernel parameter.